# How can I detect when new windows are opened and/or get a list of open windows?

Tags: java, events, window, listener

I am aware of `WindowListener` and its ilk, but these only seem to provide events for windows to which you have a reference already and can add the listener to. I'm wondering how to either receive a callback when new windows are created by other processes, or poll for a list of all windows currently open on the system.

I'm using J2SE on Mac OS X, but a cross-platform answer is ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like already said above you can only monitor windows created by Java apps. Getting that kind of information would require OS specific development (JNI).

Answer (score 1):

```
Window.getWindows();
Window.getOwnedWindows();
Window.getOwnerlessWindows();
```

But these are only Windows opened by your Java app.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not possible due to the sandbox idea behind the JRE.
You can only "see" Windows from your own process.
But I don't know for sure.